# Random number in array

Tags: java, arrays, random

```
int[] integers = new int[12];
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
    integers[i] = r.nextInt((10 - (-10) + 1) + (-10));
}
```

I'm executing it using  [online compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) and it throws an error at random.

can anyone help me to solve that problem? I don't know how to write that half of it be negative and half positive. And that random number can't be 0

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is it a compilation error? You need to import random. `import java.util.Random;`

Comment: I've imported and it's ok now. can you guys help me about filling array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to generate a number between -10 and 10, the correct code is :

```
 integers[i] = r.nextInt(21)-10;
```

`r.nextInt(21)` will generate numbers between 0 and 20, so subtracting 10 will give you the desired range.

Now, you must validate the random numbers you generated, to make sure you don't generate too many positives or negative, and no zeroes.

```
    int posCount=0;
    int negCount=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
      integers[i] = r.nextInt(21)-10;
      if (integers[i]>0) 
          posCount++;
      else if (integers[i]<0) 
          negCount--;
      if (posCount>6||negCount>6||integers[i]==0)
          i--; // redo the current iteration of the loop, since the last generated
               // number should be replaced
    }
```

Another alternative, which will run faster, is to generate first 6 positive integers (`r.nextInt(10)+1`) and then 6 negative integers (`-1-r.nextInt(10)`), but I'm not sure whether the order of the generated numbers is important (i.e. is it acceptable that all the positives will come before all of the negatives).

Answer (score 0):

`1+ r.nextInt(10)` gives integers 1-10. For negative integers, just put minus sign to the result of this calculation. Call it six times for positives and six times for negatives. What kind of error you get?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10629438)

Comment: What do you mean? It answers to the question of generating six numbers in the interval [1, 10] and six numbers in [-10, -1].

Comment: You are posting a comment as an answer.

Comment: One question was regarding generating six numbers in the given ranges, the answer was regarding that problem.

Comment: @karastojko: IMO, and just to avoid this kind of misunderstanding, try to explain your answer with a few more lines, so it really look like a good quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
 Random r = new Random();
    int[] integers = new int[10];
    boolean isEven=false;
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        int check = r.nextInt(10)*(isEven?-1:1);
        if (check != 0){
            isEven = !isEven;
            integers[i] = check;
            System.out.println(integers[i]);
            i++;
        }
        if(i == 10){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple:

- Fill the current index with a random number from (1 to 10);
- Fill the next index with a random number from (-1 to -10);

  ```
  int[] integers = new int[12];
  Random r = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i+=2) {
      integers[i] = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
      if((i+1)<integers.length){
           integers[i+1] = r.nextInt(10) -10;
      }
  }
  ```